Migrating from dart:html to web — how to listen for events?
I'm currently trying to follow the migration guide at dart.dev to update a package that relies on the now deprecated dart:html library.
Some of the updates are straightforward. For example, something like
import "dart:html" as html;

...

final canvas = html.CanvasElement(width: 100, height: 100);


becomes
import "package:web/web.dart" as web;

...

final canvas = web.HTMLCanvasElement()..width=100..height=100;


but I am struggling to handle listeners.
For example, I have something like this, which works using dart:html:
html.document.onFocus.listen((_) {
  // handle event...
});

I notice that web.document has an onfocus attached, but I can't add a listener to it...
How do we handle events, such as the above? And where can we find detailed documentation for the web package?

Define your function like void printString(web.Event event) { print(event.target); } and then assign it with: web.document.onfocus = printString.toJS. Remember to import dart:js_interop.

@julemand101 Thanks for that! I notice that I could even do it inline, which is perfect. Post your response as an answer and I'll accept it.

You can convert a Dart function into a JSFunction by calling the .toJS (from dart:js_interop) getter on your Function.
The JSFunction instance can be used to set the callback of your web.document.onfocus.
So something like:
import 'package:web/web.dart' as web;
import 'dart:js_interop';

void main() {
  void printString(web.Event event) {
    print(event.target);
  }

  web.document.onfocus = printString.toJS;
}

